# Content Porting Localized & Renamed Structure Groups Fail

Tags: content-porter-2013, structuregroups, localization

Have got a child Publication which has got many structures groups localized and renamed to have the titles in the respective local language. When I content port the entire Publication from one environment to the other environment, localized & renamed structure groups give errors due to directory name conflicts.

When I look at what happened, the child publication itself was created correctly and then it inherited all the items from the parent Publication. As the localized strcuture groups in child Publication were renamed, content porter didn't see the link with the parent item (content porter works with names of the items not with tcm uris)  but tried to create those (localized & renamed) structure groups as local items and then got into the conflict with the directory names of structure groups inherited from the parent.

Any pointers on how this issue can be fixed?

Comment: What error are you getting? I have done the same scenario multiple times and have not faced the issue and unless the "directory" was updated as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Error message: "Tridion.ContentManager.UniquenessException: Name, Directory must all be unique for items of type: Structure Group within this Structure Group and its BluePrint context. Source or sources of conflict:<TCM URI>"

Comment: When you take an export, make sure to check "export shared items as shared" and your directories should be same and not localised. My suggestion would be to try porting one structure group at a time. Sometimes, a particular structure has some issues. Also, does your local publication also have a child publication? If yes, check if that has a same directory name.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out in the right direction. However the setting is in the import flow. "Resolve shared items with BluePrint mapping" is the setting that will let us have the desired results. By default, this option is not checked.

Comment: You'll need to be careful if using GJin's suggestion above about exporting shared items as shared. The may cause items to be created at the wrong level in the BluePrint! More details on using this functionality are here: http://tridioninternals.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/export-shared-items-from-owning.html

Answer (score 2):

"Resolve shared items with BluePrint mapping" is the setting that will let us have the desired results. By default, this option is not checked.